# TTS not setting values from Pitch and SpeechRate

Tags: android

Android TTS : Why not setting value for Pitch, SpeechRate if string length greater than 4000 ?

Thanx in advanced,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not just pitch and rate that are being rejected.  The TTS request will be rejected totally if the text length is greater than 4000 characters.

see MAX_SPEECH_ITEM_CHAR_LENGTH in this extract from the [Android source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/50e657bb2d005568f5dd8bc1d904d07b0d94018f/core/java/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeechService.java):

```
public abstract class TextToSpeechService extends Service {

    private static final boolean DBG = false;
    private static final String TAG = "TextToSpeechService";

    private static final int MAX_SPEECH_ITEM_CHAR_LENGTH = 4000;
```